# Let ,, and  be natural numbers , >1, and suppose that , have no common factor. Prove that $(^ + ^)|(^+^)\implies | $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $,,$ and $$ be natural numbers, $>1$ and suppose that $,$ have no common factor.

Prove that:

If $(^+^)|(^+^)$ then $|$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$a,b,m,n$ be positive integers such that g.c.d.$(a,b)=1$ and $a^m+b^m|a^n+b^n$ , then $m|n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074649/a-b-m-n-be-positive-integers-such-that-g-c-d-a-b-1-and-ambmanbn)

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $m\geq n$ thus let $m=nq+r$ for $0\leq r \leq n-1$
thus $$a^{m}+b^{m}\equiv a^{nq}(a^{r}+(-1)^{q}b^{r})\equiv 0\ (\mod a^{n}+b^{n})$$ thus if $q$ even $$a^{r}+b^{r}\equiv 0\ (\mod a^{n}+b^{n})$$ but which is not possible for any  $0\leq r\leq n-1$ as $a>1$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$
If $q$ is odd and $$a^{r}-b^{r}\equiv 0\ (\mod a^{n}+b^{n})$$ as $0 \leq r \leq n-1$ so , $r=0$ forced as $a\geq 2$ and $\gcd (a,b)=1$ thus $n|m$ and we are done.

Comment: Please explain how did you put $a^m+b^m$ congruent to$ a^nq(a^r + b^r.(-1)^k ) $. I mean where did $ (-1)^k $ came from

Comment: $b^{m}=b^{nq+r}=b^{nq}b^{r}=(b^{n})^{q}b^{r}=(a^{n}+b^{n}-a^{n})^{q}b^{r}=(-a^{n})^{q}b^{r}=(-1)^{q}a^{nq}b^{r}\equiv (\mod a^{n}+b^{n})$

Comment: Now I need a like to my solution so please do!!! Lol just kidding !!!

Comment: I would’ve smashed that like button but I just joined yesterday. Dont ve enough ‘reputation’ to do that. 

Comment: Babes it's okay , I am kidding!!!