Divisibility of $a^m + b^m$ by $a^n + b^n$ implies divisibility of m by n
I'm working on a problem that states: Let $a, b, m, n$ be natural numbers, $a > 1$, and suppose that $a$ and $b$ have no common factors (GCD). We are asked to prove that if $a^m + b^m$ is divisible by $a^n + b^n$, then $m$ must be divisible by $n$.
I've tried using long division and modular arithmetic, but I'm stuck on how to proceed with the proof. The textbook solution simply suggests "carrying out long division," which I did without success.
After seeing the comments, one user pointed out that this problem $a,b,m,n$ be positive integers such that g.c.d.$(a,b)=1$ and $a^m+b^m\mid a^n+b^n$ , then $m\mid n$? offers the same solution.
And that is indeed similar. I have seen the answers, but I found them unhelpful. It assumed some prerequisite knowledge that I don't have, as of now, or perhaps, it skipped some steps or didn't give as elaborate of an explanation as my brain needed.
Okay, after seeing some comments, and answers, I have advanced my understanding of the problem.
So, I have assumed that $n <= m$, and I have used the division algorithm to express the following statement $m = nq + r$ for $0<=r<n$.
$a^n + b^n | a^m + b^m$. From this statement, I have thought of trying to do $a^m + b^m = (a^n + b^n)x$, and further try to solve the problem.
Can someone help me get started on the proof?  Understanding the logic and intuition behind each step would be very helpful.

Welcome to MSE. Can you show us your work using the long division? We would then understand your difficulty.

I tried to long divide a^m + b^m by a^n + b^n, as that is the first thing I saw. I didn't get any meaningful conclusions.

Try doing it with some numerical examples first (for example, fix $n=2$ and try $m=4,5,6$), and you should be able to find a pattern for the general case.

if you use long division you get a succession of $a^{m-n}b^n, a^{n-2n}b^{2n},...a^{m-kn}$ and never $a^0 $ if n does not divide m.

Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3530503/42969 .

I added a skipped step in the linked dupe. If it still is unclear then please say precisely what is not clear so we can elaborate further. $\ \ $

Here is a sketch: First show that $n\leq m$. Then note that $a^m+b^m=a^{m-n}(a^n+b^n)-a^{m-n}b^n+b^{m-n}(a^n+b^n)-b^{m-n}a^n$ $=(a^{m-n}+b^{m-n})(a^n+b^n)-a^{i}b^{i}(a^{j}+b^{j})$, where $i=\min(n,m-n)$ and $j$ accordingly either $m-2n$ or $2n-m$.
The assumptions on $a,b$ imply that  $a^n+b^n$ divides $a^{j}+b^{j}$. If $j=m-n$, then $j< m$ and if $j=2n-m$, then since $n\leq m$ we have $m\geq 2n-m$. In both cases $j\leq m$. In case of equality, $n$ divides $m$. If $j<m$ use induction, by which $n$ divides $j$ and thus $m$ as well.

How is $a^{m-n}(a^n + b^n) - a^{m-n}b^n + b^{m-n}(a^n+b^n) - b^{m-n}a^n = (a^{m-n} + b^{m-n})(a^n + b^n) - a^{i}b^{i}(a^j + b^j)$ where $i = min(n, m-n)$ and j accordingly either $m-2n$ or $2n - m$.
I am a beginner myself, in this field, and I don't understand this manipulation.

Can you be more specific on what you understand and what you don't understand about the manipulation? This way I don't know how to respond.
